# modifying UserAgent from PCL throws an error at runtime when executed from Xamarin.Android app

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, user-agent, portable-class-library

When I execute PCL code from my Xamarin.Android app I'm getting the following error:

> System.ArgumentException: This header must be modified with the
>   appropiate property

Portable Profile = Profile104
NET45 + WP75 + WIN8 + Xamarin.Android

Portable Library Code:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent] = "***";
```

The same code works absolutely fine when executed from Windows Phone application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I go with platform specific service which provides HttpWebRequest and use it via interface in my PCL. This is the only solution I managed to come up with.